# Can we convert embedded envelope to Emailed Envelope and vise versa in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We are working on the assignment to optimize the envelope generation process.

We found out that our users are creating Emailed envelope and Embedded Envelope of same documents - Is there any way we can convert Emailed Envelopes to Embedded and vise versa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a recipient and add them back as the different type.  You can also make a recipient BOTH remote and in-person by setting the EmbeddedRecipientStartURL of the signer to "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN".

Comment: Updated the accepted answer as per latest docuSign api

Answer (score 1):

At the time of Envelope creation, each recipient is specified as either Embedded (will access the envelope via your application) or Remote (will access the Envelope via link in an Email that DocuSign sends).  [This is specified via the presence or absence of the clientUserId property on each recipient in the Create Envelope API request.] Once an Envelope has been sent, it is not possible to change an Embedded recipient to a Remote recipient, or vice versa.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best answer, you can delete a recipient and add them back as the different type.  You can also make a recipient BOTH remote and in-person by setting the EmbeddedRecipientStartURL of the signer to "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN".

Comment: Good point about the **EmbeddedRecipientStartURL** property -- thanks! (This answer was provided before that property was added to the DocuSign API.)  Also a valid suggestion that you can delete a recipient of one type and then add a new recipient as the different type -- but it's important to note that this is *not* the same thing as simply being able to *change* an existing recipient from remote to embedded (or vice versa) -- b/c the new recipient is created from scratch -- no tabs, authentication settings, etc. are automatically inherited from the original recipient.